# Ingresar datos desde form c# a base de datos sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
   /*Este es la clase que ese encarga de conectar con la base datos el campo        

    nombre esta en tipo string y en la base datos esta de tipo varchar  

    entonces cuando ingreso letra en el campo nombre me sale un error (el 

     nombre de la columna "lo que ingrese en el campo" no es valido) pero  

     cuando     

     ingreso numero si lo manda a la base de datos*/



 - 

    using System; using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Linq; using System.Text; 
    using System.Threading.Tasks; 
    using System.Data.SqlClient; 
    namespace Ln { 
       class Datos { 
         SqlConnection cot = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP- 1D9F71A;Initial Catalog=prog1;Integrated Security=True"); 
         SqlCommand command; 
         public void guardar(string nombre, int edad, string carrera, int matricula) { 
         cot.Open();
         string lncom = $"insert into Estudiante values({nombre}, '{edad}', '{carrera}',{matricula} )"; 
         command = new SqlCommand(lncom, cot); 
         command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
         cot.Close(); 
         }
        } 
      }

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Al insertar datos, los `strings` deben ir rodeados de comillas.

```
string lncom = $"insert into Estudiante values('{nombre}', '{edad}', '{carrera}','{matricula}');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Roger Torne me funciono

Comment: Ojo que esta manera de usar tiene varios problemas, por ejemplo si el nombre tiene `'`.  Además tenes que formatear las fechas y numeros. La manera correcta de hacerlo es usando un [SqlParameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8)